# Call key press with javascript

Tags: javascript, forms, event-handling

I am trying to press tab and enter key through javascript/jquery on page load.

like:

```
  if(event.keyCode == 13){
    $("#submit").click();
  }
```

this would only work when user presses the enter key but I want the javascript to do this stuff for the user on page load.

Comment: you want to simulate a keypress for your code to catch it ? did i miss something or can't you find anything simplier ?

Comment: Ya, I want to simulate a keypress through javascript..

Comment: This looks really wrong, I am 99% certain there is a better way to achieve what you want. Perhaps if you explained why you need to press tab and enter on page load you'd get more helpful answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simulate a keypress with this code:

```
function simulateKeyPress(character) {
  jQuery.event.trigger({ type : 'keypress', which : character.charCodeAt(0) });
}
```

thanks to this thread: [Is it possible to simulate key press events programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/596481/simulate-javascript-key-events)

but as Ghyath Serhal pointed out, there might be a better way than to simulate a keypress to then catch it by your same code.

Answer (score 1):

Check the below if it helps

```
<body onload="$('#submit').click();"></body>
```

Comment: No, I don't want to submit a form like this. It won't work. First it needs focus, so I am trying to simulate tab key and then enter key.